# How could I know the result color when I mix the color numbers?

Tags: color, tcolorbox, colortbl

In these codes, how can i select a special color from them?

```
\definecolor{mypink1}{rgb}{0.858, 0.188, 0.478}
\definecolor{mypink3}{cmyk}{0, 0.7808, 0.4429, 0.1412}
\definecolor{Mycolor2}{HTML}{00F9DE}
```

Comment: Not understood. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: i edited the question @daleif

Comment: Are you asking for a way to know what numbers to use for a specific  colour? Use a colour picker in an image editor, or a website like https://color.adobe.com/

Comment: You want to see the result of the parsing? Assuming `xcolor` is loaded, other than the HTML entry, they are used 'as given'.

Comment: thanks @TorbjørnT. i got it

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.

Comment: To be honest, i tried to close it but i didn't  where.@StefanPinnow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here a copied answer " Use a colour picker in an image editor, or a website like [https://color.adobe.com/create/color-wheel"](https://color.adobe.com/create/color-wheel%22) – Torbjørn T.